# SDK/Tools to Develop a New App on Windows Phone Platform for WP 7, WP 7.5 , WP 8 devices

Tags: windows-phone-7, windows-phone-8

I am new to Windows Phone Development Environment, looked around on SO but couldn't find a clear answer to the question I have.

With Windows Phone SDK 8 publicly available, and new Windows Phones getting good reviews, one of our Clients is looking to launch their app on Windows Phone Platform as well (they already have it on iPhone). The app is pretty simple. Obviously Client would like their app to be compatible and available to as many as possible users/devices - WP7, WP7.5 and WP8.

Question is - what SDK version should I use to develop this app? Currently I have **Windows 8 with 64-Bit, VS 2012 Express and Windows Phone SDK 8.0** already installed and ready to go for development. So if develop app using above tools, will it run on all the devices with **WP 7,WP 7.5 and WP 8** on them?

What is a good approach to develop a brand new Windows Phone App that would run on WP 7,WP 7.5 and WP 8 Devices.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The complete answer is on this MSDN page:
[Windows Phone versions](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202996%28v=vs.105%29.aspx)
Basically you can create application targeting the WP7.5 platform and it will run on all current Windows Phone devices, or you can target only Windows Phone 8, then it will run only on new WP8 devices, but when targeting this newer platform, you can use broader set of APIs and features.

Comment: The link is great, thanks!. So from this link it seems that with Windows Phone SDK 8.0, I can target WP 7.5 and WP 8.0, but not WP 7.0. If I use SDK 7.1.1 I can target WP 7.0, WP7.5 and WP 8.0?

Comment: There is no reason for targeting old WP7.0 platform - all WP7.0 phones can be updated to WP7.5 (and vast majority is already updated) and it's not even possible on WP7.0 phones to downloads apps from store now.

Comment: Thanks Martin. Is there a link where I can read that its not possible for a WP7.0 phones to download app from store now?

Comment: Here you go: http://blogs.windows.com/windows_phone/b/windowsphone/archive/2012/05/22/starting-today-you-need-windows-phone-7-5-to-use-marketplace.aspx

Answer (score 2):

When you create new project, you are asked to choose between Windows Phone 7 and 8. 
WP7 app runs in old and newer phones, but WP8 app runs only in WP8.

Comment: Right, I am asked to choose "Windows Phone OS 7.1" and "Windows Phone OS 8.0" when creating a new project. So you are saying if I choose Windows phone 7.1, the app will work on all devices? Will the app work on WP7.0 devices as well in this case?

Comment: It should work also in 7.0 (maybe some functionalities might be missing that were implemented only in 7.1)

Comment: At the bottom of the link @Martin Suchan gave, it says I cannot develop App for WP 7.0 with SDK 8.0. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windowsphone/develop/hh202996%28v=vs.105%29.aspx

Comment: Right, thanks for heads up. But I don't think there are many 7.0 phones out to be worried about them.